# Compute value of polynomial in R

Tags: r

I have a polynomial 'p' of degree 4.
How can I compute the value of the polynomial 'p' for `x = 1:10`

```
require(polynom)  
p <- polynomial(coef = c(1:5))
p 
1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
as.function(p)(1:10)
# [1]    15   129   547  1593  3711  7465 13539 22737 35983 54321
```

whenever you want something to be something else in R, there is likely an `as.` function.

Answer (score 1):

The polynom package suggests using the `predict` function:

```
predict(p, newdata = 1:10)
# [1]    15   129   547  1593  3711  7465 13539 22737 35983 54321
```